# How do you reset Darktable on Windows

Tags: darktable

I'm having trouble with Darktable on windows, and I'd like to reset it.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it seems to remember which photos I've been using still.  Is there a config file I can delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.darktable.org/about/faq/) user settings are located here:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\darktable\darktablerc
```

where `[username]` is your username with which you login in to your OS

> Q: I read in the manual about changing some configuration setting,
>   which supposed to be located in the user config directory. Where is
>   the config file in the Windows version?
>
> A: The configuration file of darktable is located at
>   C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\darktable\darktablerc. If you change
>   it please use a text editor which can handle Unix line endings, like
>   Notepad++ or similar.

So to reset/delete all setting just delete this directory

Answer (score 0):

This does not completely remove darktable. It leaves several registry entries which seems to be messing with my re-install. Now a newly installed copy of darktable still crashes during imports of raw files...
Funny thing is the app works perfectly in Linux Mint 19.2.